# Bridging header in framework method accessibility

Tags: swift, accessibility, bridging-header

I have a framework written in Swift and some Objective-C files.

I need the Objective-C methods only in the Swift classes of my framework. 
When I add the corresponding import into the bridging header, it makes the methods available outside the framework.

Is it possible to import Objective-C code but specified the accessibility as internal or private ?

Answer (score 0):

Your framework target is actually ignoring your bridging header.  It will only look at the umbrella header, and as such, it will be available to the API you are exposing.

Please do report if you discover a way around this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html